# How to find input field with start value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got some nested `input` elements and would like to display only the one with a certain `value` passed by a `query string`.

The whole query string part is working and I stored it in a value, but my code to detect the `.main` wrapper containing the correct `input` field seems to be broken.

**HTML**

```
// multiple times the same row with different input values
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="hidden" value="4">
      <input type="text" class="hidden" value="4">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// value passed by string, for example 2:
var queryStringVal = 2;

$('.main').each(function() {
  var inputFields = $(this).find('input');

  inputFields.each(function() {
    var inputFieldVal = $(this).getAttribute('value');

    if (inputFieldVal == queryStringVal) {
      console.log("Found input field with value " + queryStringVal);
      $(this).closest('.main').show();
    }

  });
});
```

I have created this **[JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fLf6y03o/1/)** to demonstrate the problem. How can I fix this and only show the `.main` wrappers containing inputs with the right value?

Comment: Always check your console: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getAttribute is not a function` Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/vu0d0h8o/

Comment: Use `$(...).val()` to fetch input value. There is no getAttribute() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a good use case for using `filter()`

```
$('.main').filter(function() {
   return $(this).find('input').filter(function() {
         return this.value == queryStringVal;
   }).length;
}).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
 $(this).val()
```

instead of

```
$(this).getAttribute('value');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fLf6y03o/4/

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fLf6y03o/5/) you can see how to fix css for displaying only input with value `2`

Comment: thanks for this simple solution while keeping my code. It helped me understand my problem and error! For the quality of stack I have marked charlietfl's answer as it shows a simpler approach than my own one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var queryStringVal = 2;

    $(".main input").each(function(){

        var value = $(this).attr("value");

        if (value == queryStringVal)
            $(this).closest(".main").show();

    })

})
```

**Final code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var queryStringVal = 2;
    
    $(".main input").each(function(){
        
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        
        if (value == queryStringVal)
            $(this).closest(".main").show();
        
    })
            
})
```

```css
.main {
  
  display: none;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
          <div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" value="2">
              <input type="text" value="2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
<div class="main">
    <div>
      <div>
       <input type="text" value="4">
       <input type="text" value="4">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: note this will only return value of first input found, will fail if value contained in second one

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great. For the quality of stack I have marked charlietfl's answer as it shows a simpler approach than my own one.

Answer (score 1):

You my try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fLf6y03o/6/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var queryStringVal = 2;
  $('input.hidden[value='+queryStringVal+']').closest('.main').show();
});
```

Comment: what if user changes value? Attribute value and property value don't match then

Comment: It's on document ready (before any changes happen) and assumed that was a requirement.

Comment: possibly...just pointing it out, could be demo was simplified to not reflect real use case though

Comment: It could be tho :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the inputs by their values:

```js
// value passed by string, for example 2:
var queryStringVal = 2;

$('.main input').filter(function(index, element) {
  return element.value == queryStringVal;
}).closest('.main').show();
```

```css
.main {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="main">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="hidden" value="4">
            <input type="text" class="hidden" value="4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="hidden" value="2">
            <input type="text" class="hidden" value="2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="hidden" value="3">
            <input type="text" class="hidden" value="3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```